React Vite website not showing images when deployed in vercel
My react vite website is showing all the images on localhost. But when deploying on vercel, the images are not showing.
I have moved the assets folder to the public folder from src and tried deploying. Still, the issue persists. I have logged out of vercel and logged back in, tried redeploying, deploying all over again but none of these worked.
